# how to handle multiple php apps on heroku from command line?

Tags: php, git, heroku

I am using one app named, `sms-hw` in which I have worked before.

I recently created another app `protected-peak`, Immediately after creating this app, i tried pushing my work with `git push hero master` I got a statement saying that

saying it uploaded the work to my old app `sms-hw`

I actually wanted to upload it to `protected peak`

how to manage many apps like these, can i add the name somewhere, so as to avoid the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [Heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line) installed and you are already logged in:

On the repository you want to deploy to your new app use:

`heroku git:remote --app protected-peak`

You specify the app name when adding the heroku git remote now that you have more than one app. The command above will set the `heroku` remote to your new app. So after running it just use:

`git push heroku master`

More information on Heroku deploy with git [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote).